# Rails Devise registration error stay on same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, registration

Noob question.

In rails devise, I want users who can't register successfully(error) to stay on the same page as they were on. Currently they are being routed to registrations/new.html.erb on error, but what if I want it to go back to the same page with errors being thrown there instead?

Comment: Similar problem has been discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419918/ruby-on-rails-how-would-i-stay-on-the-same-page-if-the-post-is-not-saved)